# I'm making an FPS game in unity and keep getting these errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Whenever I use this code I get 2 errors I was looking into them but I couldn't really find much any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error messages:

> Assets\MouseLook.cs(1,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
> 'MonoBehaviour' could not be found
>
> Assets\MouseLook.cs(6,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
> 'Transform' could not be found

The code:

```
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensX;
    public float sensY;

    public Transform orientation;

    float xRotation;
    float yRotation;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        // Get mouse input
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

        yRotation += mouseX;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation -= Mathf.Clamep(xRotation, -90f, 90f);


        // rotate cam and orientation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
        orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have import statements at the top of your scripts?

Comment: The directive for the UnityEngine namespace is missing. "using UnityEngine" is added at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the dependencies for the MonoBehaviour and Transform class. Visual Studio or whatever IDE you use cannot recognize the class without the "using" statement in the beginning of your script.

Simply add this to the beginning:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

Read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

You can always find out what a class depends on by reading the docs:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

Comment: you are welcome. If this is the answer you were looking for, please accept it.